# How to add rows in an Access Table with parameters?

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, ms-access

This is my function:

```
Function SQL_InsertUpdate(mySQLConnection As OleDbConnection, mySQLCommand As String, mySQLTable As String, mySQLTableColumns() As String, myParameters() As String)
    Dim SQLCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(mySQLCommand, mySQLConnection)

    Dim myStringConstruct = mySQLCommand & " " & mySQLTable & " ("

    '==============
    For Each item In mySQLTableColumns
        myStringConstruct = myStringConstruct & item & ", "
    Next
    myStringConstruct = Strings.Left(myStringConstruct, Len(myStringConstruct) - 2)
    myStringConstruct = myStringConstruct & ") VALUES ("

    For i As Integer = 0 To mySQLTableColumns.Length - 1
        myStringConstruct = myStringConstruct & "@" & mySQLTableColumns(i) & ", "
        SQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & mySQLTableColumns(i), myParameters(i))
    Next

    myStringConstruct = Strings.Left(myStringConstruct, Len(myStringConstruct) - 2)
    myStringConstruct = myStringConstruct & ")"
    SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Function
```

This is how I call the function:

```
            Dim myParameters() As String = ({myNewID.ToString, myUser.ToString, myDepartment.ToString, mySubsidiary.ToString, myTitle.ToString, myRecurrence.ToString, myImpact.ToString, myTimeSaved.ToString, myPriority.ToString, myStatus.ToString, myTechnology.ToString, myDeveloper.ToString, myCostSave.ToString, myDescription.ToString, myCommentary.ToString, myDateSubmitted.ToString, myDateModified.ToString, myInReviewDate.ToString, myManagerReviewDate.ToString, myDigitalReviewDate.ToString, myRejectedDate.ToString, myInProgressDate.ToString, myDevelopedDate.ToString, myImplementedDate.ToString})
            Dim mySQLTableColumns() As String = ({"ID", "myUser", "myDepartment", "mySubsidiary", "myTitle", "myRecurrence", "myImpact", "myTimeSaved", "myPriority", "myStatus", "myTechnology", "myDeveloper", "myCostSave", "myDescription", "myCommentary", "myDateSubmitted", "myDateModified", "myInReviewDate", "myManagerReviewDate", "myDigitalReviewDate", "myRejectedDate", "myInProgressDate", "myDevelopedDate", "myImplementedDate"})

            SQL_InsertUpdate(SQLConnection, "INSERT INTO", "SIMSBase", mySQLTableColumns, myParameters)
```

This is the constructed command string output:

> INSERT INTO SIMSBase (ID, myUser, myDepartment, mySubsidiary, myTitle,
> myRecurrence, myImpact, myTimeSaved, myPriority, myStatus,
> myTechnology, myDeveloper, myCostSave, myDescription, myCommentary,
> myDateSubmitted, myDateModified, myInReviewDate, myManagerReviewDate,
> myDigitalReviewDate, myRejectedDate, myInProgressDate,
> myDevelopedDate, myImplementedDate) VALUES (@ID, @myUser,
> @myDepartment, @mySubsidiary, @myTitle, @myRecurrence, @myImpact,
> @myTimeSaved, @myPriority, @myStatus, @myTechnology, @myDeveloper,
> @myCostSave, @myDescription, @myCommentary, @myDateSubmitted,
> @myDateModified, @myInReviewDate, @myManagerReviewDate,
> @myDigitalReviewDate, @myRejectedDate, @myInProgressDate,
> @myDevelopedDate, @myImplementedDate)

This is the error I receive:

- ```
    $exception  {"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."}  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
  ```

Now I have no clue what syntax error I could have, I looked here for another person who has no issue in this Stack question: [Insert data into SQL database in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142157/insert-data-into-sql-database-in-vb-net), my syntax is similar.

I don't know what is wrong, could it give out a syntax error if the Access database columns are not Data Type Short/Long Text?

The parameters are added properly (checked the debug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I often find it too much work to create a complex insert routine. And even worse is I often don't care or want to supply all of the columns.

.net as a result has what is called a command builder for you.

And this quite much means you can write a lot of your code in a simular way to how VBA code in Access works.

So, say I want to add a new row - the table might have 50 columns, but I don't really care.

So, I can write the code this way:

```
    Dim rstHotels As DataTable

    rstHotels = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = 0")

    ' now add 3 new hotels

    For i = 1 To 3

        Dim OneRow = rstHotels.NewRow

        OneRow("HotelName") = "Hotel #" & i
        OneRow("City") = "City #" & i
        OneRow("FirstName") = "Test First name #" & i
        OneRow("Active") = True

        rstHotels.Rows.Add(OneRow)

    Next

    ' ok, added rows to rstHotels - now write back to database

    MyRstUpDate(rstHotels, "tblHotels")

    ' or update 5 rows and do compplex processing to exising data.

    Dim rstFun As DataTable = MyRst("SELECT * from tblHotels where City = 'Banff'")

    For Each MyRow As DataRow In rstFun.Rows

        MyRow("Active") = True
        ' more complex cpde here

    Next

    ' now send data changes back to database

    MyRstUpdate(rstFun, "tblHotels")
```

So, note how we don't have to have some complex insert statement, and we don't hve to write some loop that gives one hoot about the number of columns. So the .net data operations have build in all this stuff for you - little or even next to no reason for you to try and re-invent the wheel here.

And the two handy dandy code routines I have? The are :

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function


Public Sub MyRstUpdate(rstData As DataTable, strTableName As String)

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * from " & strTableName, conn)

            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daUP As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            conn.Open()
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Now, I am really rather free to just code out my general routines.

So, you need to say load up a grid, or even a combo box? You can now do this:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT ID, Salutation from tblGender ORDER BY Salutation")
```

So, for a simple insert, or even edit of some rows? No need to create some monster huge insert statement with a boatload of parameters. Just create a data table, and then use a simple data row to either add new rows, or even update existing ones.

The beauty of above is not only do you eliminate a boatload of parameters, but you also get parameter safe, and even type conversions. So, you can for example do this:

```
 OneRow("InvoiceDate") = Date.Today
```

Thus a strong typed value of "money" or integer, or datetime can be used in code - and no messey format convertions are required in most cases.

This so called "data base" first can be really handy, and often for some operations this is a lot less setup time and learning curve then say using EF, or even the previous dataset designer (EF = "Entity framework", which works really much like the older data set designer system - but introduction of these object model systems can be a big system to chew on when you just starting out).

But, no, don't write your own looping code to write out and create all the columns for a update command. (or insert command - note how that ONE routine can handle both updates or inserts. And you can even use row.Delete and then call tht update routine - it will also work!!.

If you think about this, that really amounts to a lot of work, and built in systems exist for this propose - saves you having to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: This database will be exported to MySQL eventually so this won't be a feasible solution in the near future, that's why I didn't bother using any .NET implementations for this, didn't want to write my code twice. 

It does look amazing that you can do that though, too bad you can't put this access database out there on a web application like you can do with MySQL (would make portability incredible even for end-users). Microsoft has a lot of wasted potential.

Comment: Unless, well, there is a way to do it that I do not know about, in which case this implementation would be a godsend.

Comment: Actually, what is even better is that if you change over to sql server, or MySQL? Well the table operations code as written will require ZERO changes!! - VERY MUCH why you now might even more consider what I suggest. So only your MyRst, and MyRstUpdate routine need be changed  - the rest of the code for the most part can remain100% as is, since we letting .net do the data type translations, and EVEN BETTER is we don't have parameters in our code. And while a lot of web systems do support the Access database, the front end UI and logic can't be transferred - but then again you using vb.net

Comment: Coming back to this later with a question, with this method, what will happen if 10 users download the same SQL table in a datatable and then upload it changed at the end? Isn't my method safer to use since it doesn't rely on remembering what the sql table looks like? Won't 10 concurrent users overwrite the sql table with their "older" tables?

Comment: Don't think anyone was suggesting to up-load or download some database. The posted concepts work 100% fine if you using Oracle, MySQL, ms-access, or SQL server. I fail to see ANY relevance in this regards. Where on earth was some implied, hinting, or suggesting that such a database was to be up-loaded, or downloaded from the web server? These are simple basic data operations - they will work as posted 100% against any common database - only change in code would be to use the ODBC provider, oleDB provider, or sqlprovider for sql server, other then that, this code should work with any database

Comment: To be fair this is not web based. Using .net with ms-access, or sql server? If you pull one row out of a 500,000 row table, then ONLY the one row is pulled over the network. Even as multi-user applcation (which is not a given). So using ms-access on a network with say 10 users, or using ms-access for a web site works quite much the same as any other database - the only difference is scalability - the number of users. 10 users on that network are free to edit, pull records, and edit them in a multi-user environment. Access does not pull the whole table to client side when you pull one record.

Comment: To be clear? No one is suggesting to download the whole table. We pull a blank row to get the database structure, and then use add-row. We never at any point in time pulled the whole table. And in fact, in 9 out of 10 cases, the data and record you want to work on has ALREADY been pulled to the client side software. So, you might as well use the wonderful pre-built ado.net datatable and datarow to manipulate that data. You not only get sql injection without a boatload of code, you also get strong typed conversion for each of the column types. From web based to desktop, I still often use above

Comment: You do realize that when we create (used) the cmd object, and the select * from table? We NEVER pulled the table, and NEVER exectued a reader in that code. We ONLY THEN executed a command builder. the SELECT * from table is ONLY for the command builder to then create all of the insert, update, delete commands for us. That command does NOT pull ANY data. It would if we execute a reader, or load. But look close, we setup cmd with select * from table, but never in fact pull that table, we feed the update command the existing table that had limited data.

Comment: I'm now even more confused, let's say I am using mySQL (which I am using right now), I use a datatable to get the SQL table in it, I modify it and then I update the SQL table with this new datatable, however, 9 other users have done the same at the same time, what will happen?

Comment: Wait what, that doesn't pull any data? wtf.

Comment: Nothing any different then whatever other code you write. Are they editing the SAME row? Then you going to get a write conflict. But, this problem no more, or no less exists with any approach you use, right?

Comment: correct - the update routine posted (MyRstUpdate) does NOT pull ANY data - look close, we don't execute a reader, or fill or anything. We only do a update. (in fact, any update, insert, delete) will actually correctly be executed for us.

Comment: It's possible that they will be editing the same row, yes, but it doesn't matter if there's a write conflict, whatever happens, happens in that case, up to them to fix it.

Comment: That sounds pretty convenient after all, I had no clue it doesn't pull data, it just writes the update command for me, lol.

Comment: and the delete command, and insert command. If you against that table, add a row, modify a row, and delete a row (say with rstData.Rows(5).delete? Then the ONE update command will execute all of the sql commands for you automatic. So, it actually writes all 4 commands for you automatic. You then edit, delete, and add against say the 4 records in that datatable, and send ALL changes back in one .Update command as I did. As I stated, I use this approach even for web base and sql server.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to delete a row from it, how can I do it? This is my code: https://paste.mod.gg/ambbzmrnlnxj/0, the SQL table will not delete the row, or any row at all.

Comment: You probably should start a whole new quesiton. The WHOLE idea of the using block is so that you do NOT have to close the conneciton - you don't need to close the conneciton in your code as a result. But, to delete a row, you use         rstData.Rows(5).Delete()   ------   (this would delete the 5th row - or better said mark it for deletion. You don't want to use removeAt, since that would physical remove the row, and not mark it as deleted. and with the row 100% removed, then your update command will not generate the delete row command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb.

The order of the operations was off, this is what the function should have looked like:

```
Function SQL_InsertUpdate(mySQLConnection As OleDbConnection, mySQLCommand As String, mySQLTable As String, mySQLTableColumns() As String, myParameters() As String)


    Dim myStringConstruct = mySQLCommand & " " & mySQLTable & " ("

    '==============
    For Each item In mySQLTableColumns
        myStringConstruct = myStringConstruct & item & ", "
    Next
    myStringConstruct = Strings.Left(myStringConstruct, Len(myStringConstruct) - 2)
    myStringConstruct = myStringConstruct & ") VALUES ("

    For i As Integer = 0 To mySQLTableColumns.Length - 1
        myStringConstruct = myStringConstruct & "@" & mySQLTableColumns(i) & ", "
    Next

    myStringConstruct = Strings.Left(myStringConstruct, Len(myStringConstruct) - 2)
    myStringConstruct = myStringConstruct & ")"

    Dim SQLCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(myStringConstruct, mySQLConnection)

    For i As Integer = 0 To mySQLTableColumns.Length - 1
        SQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & mySQLTableColumns(i), myParameters(i))
    Next

    SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Function
```

Basically, I was passing an incomplete command.

Comment: I think Albert D. Kallal is much simpler and more efficient. Those CRUD are a PITA.